# How do I include one application inside another?

Tags: macos, bundle

Our .app download includes a tool (another, smaller, app) with it that we'd like to allow users to run from the "Applications" folder, but we don't want them to have to download more than one file.

Is there a way to include one .app inside another that will result in the OS automatically adding both of them to the Applications folder when the user drags and drops it in there from the dmg file we distribute? Or would we have to use a package that extracts two separate applications?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that apps bundled inside other apps (i.e. helper apps) would show up in Mac OS X's (Lion) Launch Pad.  Much less from the Finder for end-users.

Apple distributes Xcode through the Mac App Store and it has many apps : Xcode, Intruments, Quartz Composer, etc.  Perhaps downloading an installer from the Store (as is done with Xcode) would be an option for you.

I realize it's an extra step for the user but I don't see how you can bundle multiple distinct apps in the App Store.

Aside from that, perhaps offer each software as a seperate download.  Or revisite if the apps actually do need to be their own islands.  Good luck!